# Error! Unknown Document Property Name in PDF Converted Word Document

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC site that allow users to upload word documents which are then converted to PDF. This part it working fine. However when viewing the PDF document inline in the browser, the top of the document says "Error! Unknown Document Property Name". I understand that this is possibly the result of 1 or more document properties not being set, but I am unable to get hold of any of the properties via the Document object returned via Interop.

I save the byte stream of the uploaded word document to a temp dir to facilitate the PDF conversion. The "file" is passed in as a param.

```
  using (var tmpFileStream = File.OpenWrite(fileSavePath))
  {
      tmpFileStream.Write(file.BinaryBytes, 0, file.BinaryBytes.Length);
      tmpFileStream.Close();
  }
```

I then open the doc but when I try to get hold of the properties and or fields all I get is "COM Object" as the value.

```
 var applicationWord = new Application();
 var wordDoc = applicationWord.Documents.Open(fileSavePath);

 var properties = wordDoc.BuiltInDocumentProperties;
 var title = properties.Item("Title");
 var author = properties.Item("Author");
```

I've also tried to iterate through the Fields collection to see if there was anything in here, but no joy either.

```
 foreach (var field in wordDoc.Fields)
 {
      var x = field.ToString();
 }
```

I also manually set the properties of the target word document, e.g. title, author but i still got the same error.

If anyone has any ideas or perhaps has addressed this issue themselves then I'd be most grateful.

Comment: Does this help?  `wordDoc.UpdateFields(); var badFields = wordDoc.Fields.Cast<Field>().Where(x => x.Type == FieldType.FieldDocProperty && x.Result.ToString().StartsWith("Error")).ToArray(); foreach (var f in badFields) { f.Remove(); }`

Comment: Hello...unfortunately not. the code seems fine.. but again I can't get anything to return. The Fields collection on the word doc object simply says COM object.. bad fields never returns anything. when viewed in a watch window its an empty array of "Field"... I added an extra linq command omitting the starts with error... just to get all fields.. that also return an empty array of "Field".